# В чем преимущество использования списка инициализации в конструкторе, над инициализацией в теле?

Tags: c++

В чем преимущество использования списка инициализации в конструкторе, над инициализацией в теле конструктора?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В теле конструктора не может быть никакой "инициализации" полей класса. В теле конструктора вы можете выполнить только модификацию (присваивание и т.п.) уже прошедшего через этап инициализации поля класса. *Инициализация* полей класса может выполняться только до начала выполнения тела конструктора (на основе списока инициализации конструктора или инициализаторов, указанных прямо в определении класса).

А преимущества инициализации в списке инициализации конструктора таковы:

1. "Инициализация" в теле конструктора - это в общем случае "переинициализация" чего-то, что уже как-то инициализировалось до начала выполнения этого тела. То есть это так называемая *двойная инициализация*. Зачем выполнять двойную инициализацию, если можно стразу правильно инициализировать поле в списке инициализации конструктора?
2. "Инициализация" в теле конструктора может быть просто-напросто невозможна. Поля-ссылки, const-поля, поля класс-типов без конструктора по умолчанию могут инициализироваться *только* на этапе инициализации, т.е. до начала выполнения тела конструктора.